# Angular: How to get element ID of item on which other element has been dropped

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag, angulardraganddroplists

I have two unordered list with draggable `<li>` items. I want the `<li>` items to be draggable and droppable on the `<li>` items of the other list and get both the id of the dragged `<li>` item and the id of the `<li>` item on which the dragged one has been dropped. currently I can get the element ID of the dragged item by doing this`event.item.element.nativeElement.id`. is it possible to get the id of the element on which the item has been dropped?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the same event and then use event.target